# How to obtain Flask request JSON data as dictionary?

Tags: python, json, jquery, dictionary, flask

Im struggling with JQuery ajax methods and Flask, trying to make an ajax call to retrieve some form.

My js code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/projects/dummyName',
       data: JSON.stringify("{'ajax': 'True'}"),
       contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           $("#myform").text(responseData);
         },
       error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('Error: '+errorThrown + ". Status: "+textStatus);
       }
});
```

Basically im adding the data parameter to let the server method that this is an ajax call. But i just cant get that data in the server as a dict. Tried millon ways, im cant make it work.

This is the dummy server method:

```
@app.route('/projects/<name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def projects(name=None):
    print(request.json)
    print(request.json['ajax'])
    if name:
        project = db.getProject(name)
        form = ProjectForm(project)

        if request.json['ajax'] == True:
            return render_template("myform.html", form=form)
        else:
            return render_template("projectView.html", form=form)
    else:
        return render_template("projects.html")
```

So, request.json returns a string:

> {'ajax': 'True'}

Of course the app breaks when try to access json['ajax'] and I get a BAD RESPONSE error msg. I thought that would give me a python dict, because otherwise what would be the difference between request.json and request.data if both are strings.

How can i get a python dict with all the data passed in the ajax call? Does it depend on the way I define the contentType? does it depend on the use of JSON.stringify or not?

Help will be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this link? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/ I have implemented this and it works great!

Answer (score 20):

The data is being put into request.json because of the mimetype of the request.  I believe you are looking for [`get_json`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.get_json).

```
@app.route('/projects/<name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def projects(name=None):
    req_json = request.get_json()
    print(req_json['ajax'])
    if name:
        project = db.getProject(name)
        form = ProjectForm(project)

        if req_json['ajax']:
            return render_template("myform.html", form=form)
        return render_template("projectView.html", form=form)
    return render_template("projects.html")
```

I do not have access to my dev machine at the moment so I haven't tested this, but it should work from my understanding of the docs.

Comment: I ended up using $.get() for retrieving the form and passing 'isajax' parameter in the request.args, this way it doesnt conflict with WTForms when parsing the form params. Finally i use $.post() to send the contents of the form.
 It seemed like the best approach since requiring a form or html is more of a GET instead of a POST sending json data in the header body, just to ask for something.
Thanks for you help!